# Why standard doesn't require std::mutex::~mutex synchronizes-with with the latest unlock

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

```
struct X
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::string str;
    
    void set(std::string s) 
    {
        auto _ = std::unique_lock(m);
        str = std::move(s);
    }
    
    ~X()
    {
        // auto _ = std::unique_lock(m);
    }
}
```

Is there any part of the standard that guarantees that `~X` will never experience race conditions inside `~string` without the commented line?

The exclusive access to the object and/or lifetime could be managed by an atomic variable with RELAXED semantics (== no other data except the fact of the end of lifetime is synched). We have a mutex to protect the access to the object, so using relaxed operation seems to be ok to synchronize exclusive access/lifetime and mutex to access the data.

If the standard would require `~mutex` to synchronize with the latest `unlock` and if we moved the declaration of the mutex below the protected data then we could afford default `~X` but without this requirement, we need always have explicit destructor which locks all the mutexes used to protect any member.

PS to help understand my question use this example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex there is a comment that accessing `g_pages` without a lock is safe. Why, which part of the standard guarantees this? The fact that both threads are joined only guarantees no multi-threaded access to the map, but it doesn't guarantee synchronize-with relationship with the latest `mutex::unlock` operation. I run many different programs trying to expose race conditions and I am pretty sure that `mutex` uses `std::atomic_thread_fence` for both `lock` and `unlock` which synchronizes with `thread.join` that must use at least some atomic to work. But the problem is standard doesn't require `mutex` to use `std::atomic_thread_fence` and it it just happens that all known to me implementations use it.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
 
std::map<std::string, std::string> g_pages;
std::mutex g_pages_mutex;
 
void save_page(const std::string &url)
{
    // simulate a long page fetch
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::string result = "fake content";
 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_pages_mutex);
    g_pages[url] = result;
}
 
int main() 
{
    std::thread t1(save_page, "http://foo");
    std::thread t2(save_page, "http://bar");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
 
    // safe to access g_pages without lock now, as the threads are joined
    for (const auto &pair : g_pages)
        std::cout << pair.first << " => " << pair.second << '\n';
}
```

PPS as was pointed out by @user17732522 the example above is guaranteed to be safe because of `thread.join`. You can remove mutex and one of the threads (just use 1 thread) and it will be safe. So I modified this example slightly to demonstrate the problem. Note that relaxed memory order is important here. If we replace it with a pair of acquire/release it will be perfectly thread-safe code, but it is also correct with relaxed if we assume `std::mutex::unlock` uses `std::atomic_thread_fence`

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::map<std::string, std::string> g_pages;
std::mutex g_pages_mutex;
std::atomic_flag g_f1 = {};
std::atomic_flag g_f2 = {};

void save_page(const std::string& url, std::atomic_flag* flag)
{
    // simulate a long page fetch
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::string result = "fake content";

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_pages_mutex);
        g_pages[url] = result;
    }
    flag->clear(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

int main()
{
    g_f1.test_and_set();
    g_f2.test_and_set();

    std::thread t1(save_page, "http://foo", &g_f1);
    std::thread t2(save_page, "http://bar", &g_f2);

    while (g_f1.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    while (g_f2.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed));

    // whether it safe to access g_pages without lock now, as the threads signaled they are done?
    for (const auto& pair : g_pages)
        std::cout << pair.first << " => " << pair.second << '\n';

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: If a mutex is locked, it is UB to attempt to destroy it. Even if it wasn't, it is unclear how it is possible to have one thread to have any access to an object while the other thread is destroying it without having all sorts of problems. Assume that the commented line is uncommented—what would happen if the line is executed and another thread tries to acquire the lock immediately after that?

Comment: My question is about NO UB case. There is only 1 thread accessing x when ~X is executed, see my other comment under bitmask answer for details

Comment: Interesting. No, I don't think the standard guarantees that, it would be totally unreasonable.

Comment: The last example works because `join` synchronizes with the completion of the thread and everything else in the thread is sequenced-before completion. The mutex is not relevant at that point.

Comment: For the rest of the question: Synchronizing in the destructor is too late. The lifetime of the object ends with invocation of the destructor. So at that point already no other thread is allowed to access any member of the object anymore. Establishing a _happens-before_ relationship through _synchronizes-with_ inside the destructor is then already too late. Also the members are in the wrong order for this to work.

Comment: @user17732522 I don't think you are correct about "Establishing a happens-before relationship through synchronizes-with inside the destructor is then already too late." dtor is a member as any other member with just specific semantics, by the standard the object is VALID until the body of dtor is finished, so there is nothing like too late here. "Also the members are in the wrong order for this to work" is written specifically and there is a sentence that accents about the wrong order and what needs to be done to make ~X() = default.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko The answer is the same as I commented on your Rust variation of the same question. You are using `memory_order_relaxed`; just because your flags read updated values doesn't mean you will observe anything that happened to `g_pages`, since you haven't established that `g_pages` needs to be read _after_ the flag loops terminate.

Comment: @GManNickG Rust question is different, the example in rust effectively doesn't use mutex at all, therefore it is an obvious race condition with relaxed memory order, but the problem in rust is that this kind of behavior (get_mut) is assumed safe which is not (keeping in mind that ALL I insist ALL requirements for converting raw pointer to Mutex are met). As I commented here and I checked it many times on many platforms using mutex.lock()/unlock in threads is ENOUGH even with relaxed memory order for flags, just because of fences. That is not covered by any standard parts or I didn't find them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort of. The standard does require you not to destroy an object who's lifetime has ended. If you run into the situation where multiple threads are trying to run `X::~X()` on the same object, you are already in UB land.

A similar argument can be made for one thread trying to `~X` some `x` and another trying to `x.set` on the same object. If you ever run into this situation you are already violating object access rules for `x`. The UB stemming from races on `x.str` are a consequence of this.

So, you should never find yourself in the situation that you need a lock in the destructor of your owning `X` to begin with. If several threads are accessing the same `x` object, have it maybe be owned outside the thread pool.

Comment: yes, sure, what you say is correct, but my question was about another problem. The case I am worried about is when ~X is guaranteed to be called when no other threads are using x, but when some other thread (not that which calls ~X) was previously called set. That means the ~string might see an outdated internal pointer -> double free. Which part of standard guarantees that in this case (no multithreaded access, but some mutations were made previously in (an)other threads) destructor of ~X will see all the stores made in other threads without locking the mutex. This is EXTREMELY common pattern

Comment: @AntonDyachenko In the scenario you describe, you must use some kind of synchronization mechanism in order to force the call to `~X` to happen after the call to `set`. If you don't do so, then it means that the `X` object might be getting destroyed during the call to `set` (and the mutex won't save you from any UB). If you do so, then it takes care of the problem: the synchronization mechanism ensures that the thread destroying the string sees the last-written value.

Comment: @BrianBi sure "If you do so, then it takes care of the problem: the synchronization mechanism ensures that the thread destroying the string sees the last-written value" can you please point out on standard that proves what you claim?

Comment: @AntonDyachenko If the `set` call, or some operation sequenced after it, synchronizes with some operation that's sequenced before the destructor call, then the write in the `set` call happens before the read in the destructor call (https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#9) and the side effect of the write is visible to the read (https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#13). If you don't have such a synchronization relationship then you have a situation where the destructor call is not guaranteed to happen after the `set` call.

Comment: @BrianBi I 100% agree with your comment until this sentence "If you don't have such a synchronization relationship then you have a situation where the destructor call is not guaranteed to happen after the set call" In my last PPS example access to g_map from the main thread is guaranteed to happen after both threads modify (under the lock) the map, but there is no synchronize-with relationship between main thread and other threads (I continue to repeat this again and again) UNLESS mutex unlock uses `std::atomic_thread_fence(release)` which is not covered by the standard but observed everywhere

Comment: @AntonDyachenko the example isn't correct. It's precisely because there is no synchronization relationship that it is NOT safe to access `g_pages` because  the access in the main thread does NOT happen after the accesses in the other threads---at least according to the standard. Maybe you find it works on real implementations, but the standard doesn't guarantee it and there's no reason why it ought to, considering you can just use acquire-release ordering to make the code correct (or acquire the mutex in the main thread).

Comment: @AntonDyachenko the definition of "happens before" does not include the case where one thread writes a value to an atomic variable and another thread reads the written value---UNLESS the write was a release write and the read was an acquire read.

Comment: @BrianBi thanks, I got what you say about happens-before, agree. "Maybe you find it works on real implementations" Yes, I am, and the only explanation for this I can think of is this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence see Notes section "an atomic_thread_fence with memory_order_release ordering prevents all preceding reads and writes from moving **past** all subsequent **stores**" This basically converts relaxed read on the main thread to acquire read and establish happens-before relationship. Can you provide anything contradicting this?

Comment: "but when some other thread [..] previously called set". In that situation you cannot do anything to rectify the problem from within `~X`. The problem you describe is that thread A stepped on `x.set` but has not concluded it. At that moment thread B decides to `x.~X`. You have no guarantee in which order which instructions will occur. So who gets the lock first *is chance*. Again: The second you step into the destructor and *any* thread is still doing anything with `X`'s members that would require a lock, *you already lost*.

Comment: @bitmask I strongly disagree with this "You have no guarantee in which order which instructions will occur" In this scenario, I just write `mutex.lock()` (or use xxx_lock class) as the very first line of my `~X` and everything will be correct. It doesn't matter if this is a destructor or an ordinary member, until the destructor body is finished the object is valid and can be concurrently accessed. Note, the fact that any member is allowed to call its own type destructor if an object is allocated via operator new which means executing dtor != there must be exactly 1 pointer to the object.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko Yes, but the problem is that you have no guarantee that the lock in `X::set` will be acquired before the lock in `X::~X` is acquired. The individual mutex sections are mutually exclusive, of course, but you don't know which is entered first.

Comment: Also, note that this: `~X { auto _ = std::unique_lock(m); }` doesn't do anything useful at all. The order of events is that `_` will be constructed, then destroyed (thereby releasing the lock), *then* `X`'s members are destroyed, no longer being protected by the lock.

Comment: @bitmask "doesn't do anything useful at all" I disagree. Untill the body of dtor is finished it does exactly what it is supposed to do, but after it is unlocked (== the body finished) and any thread tries to access the object then you have UB. To make it clear, I saw plenty of this code (lock in dtor) and wrote similar my self, but it was always the same pattern - in dtor you set flag exit under lock and block dtor on the conditional variable (on the same lock) waiting when the thread, running a member on the object, will check the flag and exit. This so common pattern, I amazed you don't know

Comment: @AntonDyachenko A call to `std::atomic_thread_fence` in the writing thread doesn't actually establish a synchronization relationship unless there's an acquire operation in the reading thread (the acquire operation can be either another fence, or an atomic operation); see [atomics.fences] in the standard. I am not surprised that there is much code out in the real world that is not correct according to the standard, but happens to work anyway.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko [You're wrong.](https://godbolt.org/z/Y5xGrda8M) Your lock dies before you're done destroying the object.

Comment: @bitmask Sure, in your example this is wrong but that doesn't make me wrong :)  mutex or Guard in your example must be a member of the same class in which another member is protected. `struct X { Member m; int f = {}; mutex m; conditional_variable cv; thread t; X() { t = thread([this] { auto l = unique_lock(m); while(cv.wait(l, [this]{ return f != 0; })) { if (f < 0) return; use(m}; f = 0; } } ); } void run() { l = try_lock(m); f = 1; } ~X{ {auto l = unique_lock(m); f = -1; } cv.notify_one(); t.join();  };`  is roughly what I have implemented many times and seen implemented by other devs;